# Using Python Openpyxl to Unmerge Cells and Assign Them Their Previous Value

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

Doed any one have a way to have python loop through a column, find merged cells, and then assing them their previous merged value? I am currently using Openpyxl.

```
print(worksheet.merged_cells.ranges)
```

I only got a way to detect the merged cell.

Comment: "then assing them their previous merged value?" Does this mean you want to recover the cell value that existed before the cell was made part of a merge? When unmerging cells they will have one of two values, either the value of the merged cell before the unmerge, which by default goes to the top left cell in the merge or None for all other cells.

Comment: So say cells A1:A4 are merge to say "data".What I want is to unmerge them and have them all have the value of "data". That is where I am stuck. Thank you for the comment!.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation from other answers in the question [openPyXL - assign value to range of cells during unmerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426662/openpyxl-assign-value-to-range-of-cells-during-unmerge). The later answers are more suitable but still needed some modification.
This mod creates a list of the merge cells first since if there is more that one set of cells to demerge the coords of later merges may be affected as the  first cells are changed. If there is only one set of merged cells then you could skip the list.

```
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

merge_list = []
for merge in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
    merge_list.append(merge)

for group in merge_list:
    print("Changing merged cells " + str(group.coord))
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(group.coord)
    top_left_cell_value = sheet.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
    sheet.unmerge_cells(str(group))
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = top_left_cell_value

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly, thank you very much I am new to Python and I don't know if I would have ever figured that out on my own. Thank you once again!